Boolean becomes false after passing it to pointerInput
I have been starting to dabble in Kotlin as I am interested in starting making android apps.
Though I am having a problem when trying to pass the isRecording boolean to TouchRecorder it always becomes false for seemingly no reason, any help?
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                AppContent(this)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppContent(activity: ComponentActivity) {
    var isRecording by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val recordedEvents by remember { derivedStateOf { mutableListOf<PointerInputChange>() } }

    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
        Column {
            Button(onClick = { isRecording = true }) {
                Text("Record")
            }
            Button(onClick = { isRecording = false }) {
                Text("Stop Recording")
            }
            Button(onClick = { recordedEvents.clear() }) {
                Text("Clear")
            }
            Button(onClick = { playRecordedEvents(activity, recordedEvents) }) {
                Text("Play")
            }
            Log.d("AppContent", "Recording: $isRecording, Events: ${recordedEvents.size}")
            TouchRecorder(isRecording = isRecording) { change ->
                recordedEvents.add(change)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TouchRecorder(
    isRecording: Boolean,
    onTouchEvent: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit
) {
    Log.d("TouchRecorder", "isRecording = $isRecording")
    Surface(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, _ ->
                Log.d("TouchRecorder", "isRecording: $isRecording, drag: $change")
                if (isRecording) {
                    onTouchEvent(change)
                    change.consume()
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
    }
}

Whilst trying to diagnose the issues I added the logs seen in the code but have no clue as to why it is happening.

The problem is with the pointerInput modifier where you detect that isRecording is false. That modifier works similar to remember in the way that it only re-executes if the key parameter(s) have changed.
The first time that modifier is executed, at app startup, isRecording will be false. You provided Unit as key parameter so this will only update when that changes. Unit cannot change, though, so whatever happens around that modifier, the modifier itself will be unaffected by it. Setting isRecording to true works as expected, but the pointerInput will still use the old lambda where it was false.
To fix that, just replace Unit with isRecording.
